# SQL subtraction across two tables when two tables does not match

Tags: sql-server

I have two SQL select queries which return two columns as you can see in the image below. What I want to do is subtract second query's `UnsuppliedQty` from the first query's relevant stock code's `Total` column.

Could you guide me the different approaches to do it in here.

[image: SQL Query]

Update: Using the query below, I was able to perform the subtraction, however it gives `null` when the where clause does not match with first table. In this case, I want to return the original value it had.

How do I do it?

```
select stockcode, totalstock -(
   select UNSUP_QUANT
   from SALESORD_LINES 
   where stockcode='AIRFIL01' 
   and UNSUP_QUANT<>0 
   and dbo.STOCK_ITEMS.STOCKCODE = SALESORD_LINES.STOCKCODE) 
from STOCK_ITEMS
```

Comment: Join the two tables?

Comment: You refer to an attached image which you haven't attached. Please edit

Comment: can you post the query for reference

Answer (score 1):

You may use a simple Join, Like this

```
;WITH SL
AS
(
    SELECT
        StockCode,
        UNSUP_QUANT = SUM(ISNULL(UNSUP_QUANT,0.00))
        FROM SALESORD_LINES
            WHERE ISNULL(UNSUP_QUANT,0.00) <> 0
            GROUP BY StockCode
)
SELECT
    SL.StockCode,
    TotalStock = SI.TotalStock - SL.UNSUP_QUANT
    FROM STOCK_ITEMS SI
        LEFT JOIN  SL 
            ON SL.StockCode = SI.StockCode
```

Comment: Can you suggest me a way of doing this using subquery?

Comment: Just use the cte as sub query. Both have same effect